# Remove app default when migrate in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm been confused when migrating class models in Django the class name automatically change and it add app_ in the beginning of the table name, for example I have these models

```
class lib_year(models.Model):
year = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class lib_period(models.Model):
period = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class lib_semester(models.Model):
semester = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

> When migrate it  the table name change to app_lib_year, app_lib_period, app_lib_semester
> is there anyway how to remove default app_? when migrate models

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
class lib_year(models.Model):
        year = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class Meta:
        db_table = "lib_year"
```

*From , Meta db_table you can name the database table name whatever you want In your case you want to remove prefix app_ that will be easily done by Meta db_table*

Comment: I've already tried that, but the result is the same

Comment: theres nothing wrong when calling a models. for example `data = lib_year.objects.all()`  I always used that instead of  `app_libyear.objects.all()`   but the thing is when migrate theres an app_  in my app_libyear database

Comment: use the code snippet i provide and run command makemigrations and migrate . after that the changes reflected on to the database .

Comment: thanks It works now, but I also tried this earlier but not working, Thanks it's ok now

Comment: Welcome jessica